# Convert user access query from postgreSQL to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, privileges, user-roles

I am working on converting a  PostgreSQL query to SQL server and trying to understand what exactly the query below is doing . I understand the joins but the rest is not clear at all . Could anyone please help me out here .

```
select c.name 
 FROM CNT c
 LEFT JOIN shares s ON
 c.id = s.id AND s.username::name = "current_user"()
  WHERE c.username::name = "current_user"() OR 'admin'::text = (( SELECT user_role_privs.granted_role
          FROM user_role_privs
          WHERE user_role_privs.granted_role = 'admin'::text)) OR s.username IS NOT NULL AND s.grantee_username::text <> ''::text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the query below is the SQL Server equivalent.  I added the dbo schema name and statement terminator to illustrate best practices but that is not technically required.

```
SELECT  c.name
FROM    dbo.CNT AS c
        LEFT JOIN dbo.shares s ON c.id = s.id
                              AND s.username = CURRENT_USER
WHERE   c.username = CURRENT_USER
        OR IS_MEMBER(N'admin') = 1
        OR s.username IS NOT NULL
        AND s.grantee_username <> '';
```

Comment: Thanks for this but `dbo.user_role_privs` doesn't seem to be a  valid object in SQL Server . It looks like a postgreSQL system table .

Comment: I changed to use the IS_NUMBER function, which returns 1 if the current user is a member of the specified database role.